# How to get the bug fixes or patches between two linux kernel versions?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to find information related to the bugs that have been fixed between two kernel versions.

Lets say on my ubuntu the current kernel version is 5.4.0, so i want to know what are bugs or security risks that are fixed between 5.4.0 - 5.4.1 or 5.5.0

Comment: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.4.1 https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.5 https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it is not obvious to the questioner but the question is a little ill-specified. Let me explain.

The issue is: what is a "kernel version" in the context of this question ?

For the "main" (upstream, i.e. ultimately https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/ or one of the maintained branches thereof) Linux development, the "version" is a `git` commit tag of sorts, and differences / changelogs can be found and created using the `git` command, like:

```
~/build/linux$ git log --pretty=oneline  v5.15-rc5..v5.15-rc6
519d81956ee277b4419c723adfb154603c2565ba (tag: v5.15-rc6) Linux 5.15-rc6
cd079b1f870729a9fe3294f800dff18b548f129d Merge tag 'libata-5.15-rc6' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dlemoal/libata
f2b3420b921d142b4c55f7445385bdab4060d754 Merge tag 'block-5.15-2021-10-17' of git://git.kernel.dk/linux-block
cc0af0a95172db52db2ab41b1e8a9c9ac0930b63 Merge tag 'io_uring-5.15-2021-10-17' of git://git.kernel.dk/linux-block
3bb50f8530c9cb5ec69c0744b7fd32d0ca404254 Merge tag 'for_linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mst/vhost
be9eb2f00fa7245116d49f76614054cce8e07af8 Merge tag 'powerpc-5.15-4' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/powerpc/linux
...
```

So that part is "easy".

But this is not at all the same thing as a ubuntu kernel changelog, even for the same version tags ... and they're *never the same*.

To start with, Ubuntu (and Debian, and certain other distributions) split the kernel build into *multiple packages*. They can contain different changes even when "version tagged" in the same way.

In my case, currently Ubuntu 20.04, I have:

```
~/build/linux$ dpkg -S /lib/modules/`uname -r` /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r`
linux-modules-5.11.0-38-lowlatency, linux-headers-5.11.0-38-lowlatency: /lib/modules/5.11.0-38-lowlatency
linux-image-5.11.0-38-lowlatency: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-lowlatency
```

i.e. three packages, `linux-modules`, `linux-headers` and `linux-image`.

One can ask the package subsystem (`apt`) for (`*.deb` package) changelogs on these:

```
$ apt changelog linux-image-5.11.0-38-lowlatency

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Get:1 https://changelogs.ubuntu.com linux-signed-hwe-5.11 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1 Changelog [102 kB]
linux-signed-hwe-5.11 (5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1) focal; urgency=medium

  * Master version: 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1

 -- Stefan Bader <stefan.bader@canonical.com>  Tue, 28 Sep 2021 17:39:40 +0200

linux-signed-hwe-5.11 (5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2) focal; urgency=medium

  * Master version: 5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2

 -- Stefan Bader <stefan.bader@canonical.com>  Fri, 24 Sep 2021 10:43:02 +0200
...
```

but as you can see these "meta-refer" - to Ubuntu's main distribution kernel branches.

At this point ... you deeply jump into distribution-dependent behaviour (Ubuntu packages/maintains their kernels differently from how Debian does, not to talk about differences to RHEL/CentOS or Alpine, or or or or ...).

For Ubuntu, the "distro kernels" are available on git, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide and you can again clone that and query it for differences (now using the "Ubuntu version" tags) just as shown above for mainline. I leave that as an exercise to the reader :-)

For other Linux distributions (RHEL derivatives, to start with), the *package* changelogs contains short descriptions of the changes applied together with (distro) bug numbers, `rpm --changelog kernel` (usually). But at least Redhat does not have an open/public git repo that you could use to see the actual codechanges behind.

To explain the reasons why (and how, i.e. when/how they sync with mainline and/or selectively backport) distributions maintain their own kernel trees would take a lot more than the margin of this SO post; I'll defer on this for now, as off-topic wrt. to the main question.